# Input type number is showing problem if min and max are used

Tags: javascript, html

I have create a function in java script to allow user to type in input values from 0 to 99. Function is called on keypress event (in Backbone/Marionette).

```js
events: {
    'keypress #input-nr': 'maxValue'
}

maxValue(e) {
    return e.target.value.length !== 2;
}
```

Input:

```html
<input
    id="input-nr"
    type="number"
    class="form-control"
    min="0"
    max="99"
    maxlength="2"
    value="{{value}}"
/>
```

The issue that I'm getting is that when user try to select from keyboard whole numbers, and try to replace with another, is not allowed, or if user try to select whole numbers (if use CMD + A to select all) and try to press Backspace to remove, can't do it.

Comment: You want to allow the value `0`, but reject everything that is not exactly two characters in length? Makes no sense to begin with.

Comment: Why would this need the script part in the first place, if you have `min` and `max` set on the number input field to begin with?

Comment: I want to allow user to tape numbers from 0 to 99, this function is working to do achieve that, but is showing others problem (with keyboard) i.e if user try to select all numbers in input field and want to replace with others, can't do that, or instead of replacing to press backspace key from keyboard

Comment: I need this function because if I use only min and max, it works only for top and bottom arrow in the field, not from keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

add **step=1** or step=0.1, and **remove maxlength attribute** here.

```
<input
id="input-nr"
type="number"
class="form-control"
min="0"
max="99"
step="1"
value="{{value}}"
/>
```

Comment: this works only if I use mouse to increase numbers (by using arrows in input field) not if I use keyboard to type numbers up to 99

Answer (score 0):

Try the input event instead keypress:

```
events: {
    'input #input-nr': 'maxValue'
}
```

also see if this check is any better ?

```
maxValue(e) {
    return (e.target.value>=0 && e.target.value<=99);
}
```